# How can I run protractor inside grunt?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, protractor, yeoman

Just started to use grunt so plse dont downvote straight away. I have generated a Yeoman angular app working with Grunt. The testing task looks like this:

```
   return grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'env:all',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:test',
            'injector',
            'autoprefixer',
            'karma'
            ,'protractor'
        ]);
```

The karma and protractor tests run when I call grunt test:client. Now I would like those tests to run when I serve the app, I got:

```
 grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'env:all',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:server',
            'injector',
            'wiredep',
            'autoprefixer',
            'express:dev',
            'wait',
            'open',
            'test:client',
            'watch'
        ]);
```

When I go 'grunt serve' the karma unit tests run fine but the protractor ones are not running generating this error:

```
Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:9000/#/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
```

So it is like the app is not running yet would be my guess? Is it possible to integrate protractor in a gruntFile when serving your app? Or do I need to run 2 seperate processes one with serving and one with testing?

Comment: Theorically it should run. But debug Yeoman seed is kinda complicated (I usually make my own seed). --- Still if you need some help, you will need to throw in more inforamtions. --- What is insdie your protractor config file? What is insdie the dependcies in your `package.json` file?